# Unix Shell Programming

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Have an input file with 200 lines, each line just one field which is a number.
E.g.

```
89970060122507635800
```

I need to create one output file in a way that it will look like for every input line like following:

```
INSERT,89970060122507635800,425062250763580,,0000,29514215,0000,29514215,,,,NORMAL,425062260621583,Blank,sim,9877
```

where:

1. All the fields have constant value (including empty values within commas) except the Second and the Third one
2. Second field is filled by input file, the third one is obtained by removing last digit from the second field and replace at the beginning 899700601 with 42506 (as in the example).

I'm sure I can find ways how to do that (and I will try before getting answers) but I'm more interested in knowing which could be the more efficient in your opinion. Awk, sed, a shell script using both?

Comment: "Kindly provide me with full solution to get the best option." That's the kind of sentence that will get your question closed, so I removed it. As is, it would still have been better if you had done your research *before* asking a question. "I'm sure I can find ways how to do that..."

Comment: You could likely do this with any of the shell, `sed` or `awk`. I would suggest `awk` before the shell and the shell before `sed`.

Comment: Asking for advice in picking a tool to use is hard to salvage from "too broad". There's no shortage of approaches that will work -- including native shell with no external tools (no sed, no awk, no anything else) -- but it comes down to a matter of opinion unless you give enough details to recognize what kind of efficiency matters. (Are we handling a small enough number of lines that we care about minimizing startup time, or a large enough number that we care most about maximizing throughput? Do we have a high-performance shell such as ksh93 available, or do we need to deal with bash? etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace the beginning "123" from the input with "AAA" and trim the last digit for the third field.

```
awk -v OFS="," '{$2=substr($1,1,length($1)-1); gsub(/^123/,"AAA",$1); print "bla bla bla",$1,$2,"bla bla bla"}'
```

replace the magic values and add the proper template for the print statement.

Comment: sorry dear but gsub does not work somehow. I did something similar in awk file but it will trim the last digit , not substituting those digits :-(

Comment: sorry again, my BAD...it did work and it  was similar to the way I did it :-)